# Reload iframe only when iframe contents are new?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

**Short version:**

How could an HTML file that has an `iframe` pointing to another HTML file on the same server automatically reload that `iframe` whenever the `iframe`'s content is *new*?

**Context:**

I'm using an HTML/Javascript file to watch for new instructions from a Python program. The Python program rewrites a simple HTML file when there are new instructions to see.

So my easy solution is a bit of Javascript that forces a reload of the `iframe` src every second.

However, this causes a flash of the content every time the `iframe` loads, and most of the time the information isn't new.

Instead, I'd prefer for the HTML file to *only* force a reload of the `iframe` src when it's new. Is this possible?

Comment: if you're watching a python program, why don't you send a response back from the python program every time html file is rewritten

Comment: Send a response back to *what*? I've just got an HTML file loaded in Chrome, reloading an iframe---how would Python notify the loaded HTML about new info being available?

Comment: how are you watching your python program? are you using ajax?

Comment: The python (re)writes an HTML file when it has new info to report. A local HTML file loaded in Chrome keeps reloading the python-written HTML in an iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an AJAX request to check if the `iframe` has changed.

```
var value;
(function check() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '/url/toIframe'); // change this to the correct URL
    xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
        if(value === undefined) {
            value = this.responseText;
        } else if(value != this.responseText) {
            value = this.responseText;
            // refresh iframe!
        }
        setTimeout(check, 1000); // check again in another second
    });
    xhr.send();
})();
```

This makes requests to the server to see if the content has changed. There is one second between each the end of a request and the start of the next check. (And currently, there is no error handling if the server goes down.)

---

FYI, if the server sends a `Last-Modified` header, you could actually make a HEAD request and just check that header. If you don't know what I am talking about, don't worry about it.

Comment: I'm guessing this requires a server? I was just loading an HTML file from disk in Chrome. Happy to try the server route. Pretty sure your HEAD suggestion would require a server for sure.

Comment: "pointing to another HTML file on the same server ". Don't you have a server? If you don't, you can go to the where you have these files and run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`. Go to `localhost:8000` and you'll see your files.

Comment: strange, your solution seems to work for a while but then gets sluggish. what I mean is that when I first load the file and then make changes in the iframe src, the changes load (in the calling html) immediately upon save. but if I come back to it after a while and make another change to the src iframe, those changes don't appear for a while (e.g. 10-20 sec). ideas?

Comment: I added a `?randomnumber` to the end of the URL and that dealt with it. Must be a cache issue.